# Can't export figure in matlab

Tags: matlab, pdf, export, figure

So I tried to export a .fig I had saved a few months ago into a .pdf.

Whenever I click on file->save as and choose the .pdf type I get this error:

> Undefined function 'printCallback' for input arguments of type 'matlab.graphics.shape.internal.PointDataTip'

I get the same error when using `hgexport(myFig,'myFig.pdf')` manually.

Comment: It much better if you provide a [Minimum Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com//help/mcve) i.e. provide an example small enough so that people can copy, paste and run it on their own machine. It is impossible for anybody help you as it is because we can't test it to see if it occurs on our machines as well.

Comment: Hi @kkuilla as described in my question, I am using ``hgexport(myFig,'myFig.pdf')`` whereas myFig is any figure you want...

Comment: You don't have to create a [Minimum Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you don't want to but it is very unlikely that you are going to get a useful answer as your question is now because you haven't included any details. 
It is difficult for anybody to answer this question without details. Please read [Minimum Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and update your question accordingly.

Comment: Is this behaviour consistent with all the .fig files or just a specific fig file which you saved a few months ago? Are you able to save as jpg/png? Any chance that you modified/overshadowed any MATLAB function? Which MATLAB version/release do you have?

Comment: Hi @SardarUsama it is only with this one specific figure. I am using Matlab R2019b and all the figures were created using Matlab R2018b. However, all other figures can be exported fine, except for one ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok it works now.

The Problem was, that I had selected a data point in the figure with my cursor.
After deselecting the point it worked.

I personally didn't find anything about this issue on the internet, might be interesting for others maybe...

Comment: Worked for me as well. Can you please accept your own answer?